# Is it possible to reveal the relief parameters “slope inclination” and “slope exposure” by dint of ASTER GDEM?

Tags: dem, aster

I’m trying to find information in technical and scientific articles – is it possible to reveal the relief parameters “slope inclination” and “slope exposure” by dint of ASTER GDEM? Or we can define from it the only parameter of relief – the height above sea level?
I can’t find any articles that confirm this possibility, nor reject it.

If it’s possible, could you tell me the way to do it or the direction from which I can start searching for this information?

Comment: You can start by computing the slope inclination and slope direction with gdaldem tool http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html. Use `gdaldem slope` and `gdaldem aspect`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!
Also I've found these options in ArcGIS 10:

1. Aspect Tool (Spatial Analyst - Surface) for surface direction
2. Slope Tool (Spatial Analyst - Surface) - for surface inclination.

For both tools I moved the ASTER GDEM raster from Geographic (lat/lon) original coordinate system to UTM (WGS_1984_UTM)  coordinate system. And (in the Slope Tool) assigned Z factor as "1".

Hope I was right.